# Extracting the duration of a 3GP video file in Java/ Android

Tags: java, android, video, 3gp

I am absolutely new to Android Development and am trying to create a small Video Player which can record videos and view recorded videos. I am viewing the list of videos recorded by the app in a ListView where for each video I show the title and length of the video.

I fetch a list of videos using:

```
File[] fileList = directory.listFiles(filter);
```

I have been able to fetch the name of the video using the following:

```
fileList[i].getName()
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to extract the length/ duration of the video. I could not find any relevant APIs which does so as well.

How can I get the duration of a 3GP video file in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Cursor like this ...

```
 String[] proj = {
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION };

            videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);
```

you can get Video file Duration using `MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION`.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: So, should I not use File[] at all and use Cursor instead? 'managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj,null,null,null);' Does this method fetch all the videos in the SD Card? I want all the videos only from a particular directory in the SD Card.

Comment: Just to let everyone know that the duration is in milliseconds.

Comment: hi i am using same code,but i am getting duration 0 each time after recording video.Is it because i have recorded video recently and its content data is not available?Please help me if any one have solution for same issue.

Comment: how to use it with fileList[i]?